# showing result of join with special format

Tags: php

I joined  two table.
with this query

```
Select P.P_id,p.P_title,p.P_text,p.P_date,tag.tag_name from p inner join tag.tag_name on p.P_id=tag.tag_pid where P.P_id=8
```

Result table is like this:

```
P_id    |   P_title |  P_text   |  P_date   |tag_name

8       |   title   |  text     |  date     |  Tag1

8       |   title   |  text     |  date     |  Tag2

8       |   title   |  text     |  date     |  Tag3

9       | title2    | text2     | date2     |  Tag4

9       | title2    | text2     | date2     |  Tag5

9       | title2    | text2     | date2     |  Tag1
```

I like showing  this result  with this format in html by using php:

```
title   | text  | date  | Tag1,Tag2,Tag3

title2  | text2 | date2 | Tag4,Tag5,Tag1
```

Comment: You just want to group results together?

Comment: yes. I want group result together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), then you don't need to do anything PHP side. You can use just `$results['all_tags']` and they'll already be comma separated.

```
SELECT P.P_id, 
       p.P_title, 
       p.P_text, 
       p.P_date, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(tag.tag_name SEPARATOR ",") AS all_tags
FROM p 
INNER JOIN tag.tag_name ON p.P_id=tag.tag_pid 
WHERE P.P_id=8
```

Comment: hello my question is edited. by GROUP_CONCAT not working correctly.